# LibGDX FreeTypeFontGenerator huge font disappearing characters

Tags: java, fonts, libgdx, freetype

I'm using FreeTypeFontGenerator to generate my fonts for my game. The font I'm using is `OpenSans-Regular.ttf`.

When using a font size of around 110 everything is fine, but when I use something higher like 160, some characters disappear. For example:

> YOU WIN!

becomes

> YOU W N!

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is caused by characters not fitting on the texture page.
Fixed by calling

```
FreeTypeFontGenerator.setMaxTextureSize(FreeTypeFontGenerator.NO_MAXIMUM);
```